# Scraping Reuters for Company Metrics

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape company metrics from Reuters.  I had this working successfully prior to them changing their website layout.  Here is what I was using and it worked well when scraping over 1500 companies.

```
for item in soup_cash_flow_annual.findAll(text='Cash from Operating Activities'):
    net_operating_cashflow_annual = item.find_next('span').text
print(str(net_operating_cashflow_annual))
```

Link to an example company:
https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/ANZ.AX/financials/cash-flow-annual.

I've been working on this for over a week and I've ran out of ideas. (I'm new to python and web scraping)

My Question:
Can someone please help me with Python in extracting the "*Cash from Operating Activities*" metric?


TIA for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When JavaScript runs in browser (doesn't happen with requests) data is loaded dynamically from a script tag. You can actually regex out the data of interest and handle with json. I've set the regex pattern to match a little more than strictly necessary in case you want other financial statement data.

```
import requests
import re
import json

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/ANZ.AX/financials/cash-flow-annual')
data = json.loads(
    re.search(r'Fusion.contentCache=(.*?);Fusion', r.text).group(1))
financials = [k for k in data['quote-by-rics-v2'].keys()
              if 'financialStatements' in k][0]
items = data['quote-by-rics-v2'][financials]['data']['result']['market_data'][0]['financialStatements']['cash_flow']['interim']['cashFromOperatingActivities']['items']
print(items)
```